# Unable to display multiple progress bars (from my class) on the terminal using threads, why?

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, c++17, c++14

I am trying to implement a feature to print multiple progress bars on the screen using threads. I have a `ProgressBar` class which produces progress bars (in case you need more info about it you can look [here](https://github.com/JustWhit3/osmanip/blob/main/src/progress_bar.cpp), the mutex locks have been removed from that), it has an `update` method, to update the bar inside a loop.

Then, I am creating a new `MultiProgressBar` class to manage multiple progress bars with threads and display them at the same time in the terminal.

```
#ifndef MULTIPROGRESSBAR_H
#define MULTIPROGRESSBAR_h

#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>
#include <tuple>
#include <functional>
#include <mutex>
#include <atomic>
#include <utility>

namespace osm
 {
  template <size_t... Is>
  struct indices {};
  
  template <size_t N, size_t... Is>
  struct gen_indices: gen_indices <N - 1, N - 1, Is...> {};
  
  template <size_t... Is>
  struct gen_indices <0, Is...>: indices<Is...> {};
  
  template <class... Indicators>
  class make_MultiProgressBar 
   {
    public:
  
     template <class... Inds>
     make_MultiProgressBar( Inds&&... bars ): bars_{ std::forward <Inds> ( bars )... } {}
  
     static size_t size() { return sizeof...( Indicators ); }
  
     template <class Func, class... Args>
     void for_one( size_t idx, Func&& func, Args&&... args )
      {
       call_one( idx, gen_indices <sizeof...( Indicators )> (), std::forward <Func> ( func ), std::forward <Args> ( args )... );
      }
  
     template <class Func, class... Args>
     void for_each( Func&& func, Args&&... args ) 
      {
       call_all( gen_indices <sizeof...( Indicators )> (), std::forward <Func> ( func ), std::forward <Args> ( args )... );
      }
  
    private:

     template <size_t... Ids, class Func, class... Args>
     void call_one( size_t idx, indices <Ids...>, Func func, Args&&... args )
      {
       std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock{mutex_};
       [](...) {} 
        (
         (idx == Ids &&
          ( ( void ) std::forward <Func> ( func )( std::get <Ids> ( bars_ ), 
              std::forward <Args> ( args )... ), false ) )...
        );   
      }
  
     template <size_t... Ids, class Func, class... Args>
     void call_all( indices <Ids...>, Func func, Args&&... args )
      {
       auto dummy = { ( func( std::get <Ids>( bars_ ), args...), 0 )... };
       ( void )dummy;
      } 
  
     std::tuple <Indicators&...> bars_;
     std::mutex mutex_;
   };
  
  template <class... Indicators>
  make_MultiProgressBar <typename std::remove_reference <Indicators>::type...>
  MultiProgressBar( Indicators&&... inds ) 
   {
    return { std::forward <Indicators> ( inds )... };
   }
  
  template <class T> 
  struct type_identity 
   {
    using type = T;
   };
  
  struct updater 
   { 
    template <template <class> class PB, class bar_type>
    auto operator()( PB <bar_type>& pb, typename type_identity <bar_type>::type v ) const
        -> decltype( pb.update( bar_type{} ) ) 
     {
      return pb.update( v );
     }
   };
 }

#endif
```

and in a main program should work as:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <chrono>
#include <cmath>
#include <iomanip>
#include "../include/osmanip.h" //Header containing ProgressBar class and others.

using namespace osm;
using namespace std;
using namespace std::this_thread;
using namespace std::chrono;

  ProgressBar<int> prog_int;
  prog_int.setMin( 0 );
  prog_int.setMax ( 100 );
  prog_int.setStyle( "complete", "%", "#" );
  prog_int.setBrackets( "[", "]" );

  ProgressBar<int> prog_int_2;
  prog_int_2.setMin( 5 );
  prog_int_2.setMax ( 25 );
  prog_int_2.setStyle( "complete", "%", "#" );
  prog_int_2.setBrackets( "[", "]" );

  ProgressBar<float> prog_float;
  prog_float.setMin( 0.1f );
  prog_float.setMax ( 12.1f );
  prog_float.setStyle( "complete", "%", "#" );
  prog_float.setBrackets( "[", "]" );

  auto bars = MultiProgressBar( prog_int, prog_int_2, prog_float );

  // Job for the first bar
  auto job1 = [&bars]() {
    for (int i = 0; i <= 100; i++) {
      bars.for_one(0, updater{}, i);
      sleep_for( milliseconds( 100 ) );
    }
    cout << endl;
  };

  // Job for the second bar
  auto job2 = [&bars]() {
    for (int i = 5; i <= 25; i++) {
      bars.for_one(1, updater{}, i);
      sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(200));
    }
    cout << endl;
  };

  // Job for the third bar
  auto job3 = [&bars]() {
    for (float i = 0.1f; i <= 12.1f; i += 0.1f) {
      bars.for_one(2, updater{}, i);
      sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(60));
    }
    cout << endl;
  };

  thread first_job(job1);
  thread second_job(job2);
  thread third_job(job3);

  first_job.join();
  second_job.join();
  third_job.join();
```

The problem is that when I run the code, progress bars are printed overlapped, like this:

```
0 [00:53] gianluca@ubuntu:~/osmanip (main)$ ./bin/main.exe 
[##                      ] 9.166668%
```

Instead I want something like:

```
0 [00:53] gianluca@ubuntu:~/osmanip (main)$ ./bin/main.exe 
[############            ] 45%
[#########               ] 39%
[##################      ] 72%
```

I found in [this example](https://www.cppstories.com/2020/02/inidicators.html/#:%7E:text=Let%E2%80%99s%20work%20on,in%20new%20lines.) that a solution may be the one of using an `std::atomic<bool>` variable in the `MultiProgressBar` class and when it is `True` move the cursor up, else doesn't do anything, like in this example, from the link I put (this is the definition of a method of a `MultiProgressBar` class to call the `update` methods, here called `write_progress`, of the other single progress bars):

```
public:
//Some code...
//...
  void write_progress(std::ostream &os = std::cout) {
    std::unique_lock lock{mutex_};
    
    // Move cursor up if needed
    if (started_)
      for (size_t i = 0; i < count; ++i)
        os << "\x1b[A";
        
    // Write each bar
    for (auto &bar : bars_) {
      bar.get().write_progress();
      os << "\n";
    }

    if (!started_)
      started_ = true;
  }
//Some code...
//...
private:
  // [...]
  std::mutex mutex_;
  std::atomic<bool> started_{false};
```

However I don't understand where and how I should put an `std::atomic<bool>` variable inside my `MultiProgressBar` class. Sorry, but I am still learning how to use threads. Can someone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that each bar erases the line, but doesn't update its row before doing it, so all just erase the same line every time. In the post you linked, the `MultiBar` class is in charge of erasing and writing, so yours must do the same. As in your case each bar erases and writes itself from the `for_one` method, your `MultiProgressBar` must at least update the cursor of the row before calling the update of the bar. Here's the pseudocode to do it:

```
updateOneProgressBar(barIndex){

  rowDiff = lastUpdatedBarIndex - barIndex

  if(rowDiff < 0) // move upwards
      moveCursorUp(-rowDiff)
  else // move downwards
      moveCursorDown(rowDiff)

  // now the cursor is in the correct row
  eraseAndRewriteBar(barIndex)

  // don't forget to update the control variable
  lastUpdatedBarIndex = barIndex
}
```

Answer (score -2):

You cannot do this without using a console graphics library of some kind, because there is no way to move the cursor up to write to a previous line.  You will need something like `curses`, or the Win32 console APIs like `SetConsoleCursorPos` and friends.

Comment: You are wrong: see for example here: https://www.cppstories.com/2020/02/inidicators.html/ character \x1b[a moves the cursor up.

Comment: Sometimes.  Depends on your terminal.